# Why does typescript allow assignment of a readonly type to a non-readonly?

Tags: typescript, immutability, readonly

I am surprised that I can assign a readonly type to its mutable type, thus surpassing the immutability feature.

```
export class Todo {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public active = true,
        public completed = false,
        public editing = false) { }
    public toString() { return this.name }
}

function f() {
    let ro: Readonly<Todo> = new Todo("bugs bunny")
    ro.name = "duffy duck" // Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property. ts(2540)
    let t: Todo = ro // allowed!
    t.name = "duffy duck" // so we can modify
}
```

The problem is that we can pass readonly instances to functions that require mutable instances and then mutate them.

Is there a way to enforce immutablility better in typescript?

Comment: The only "better" way I know of would be to abandon properties in favor of Java-like getters and setters.  See the linked q/a for the official explanation for your title question (which differs from your question in the bottom of the post, but I think the answer to that bottom one is mostly "no")